# How to convert Objective-C NSData to Swift Data?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsdata, language-interoperability

I have a NSData in Objective-C, the NSData has value `0x10`, code like bellows:

```
@implementation BufUtil
+ (NSData *_Nonnull) getOCBuf {
    std::vector<uint8_t> sendData = {0x10};
    NSData * reqBuf = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:sendData.data() length:sendData.size() freeWhenDone:false];
    NSLog(@"getOCBuf, oc NSData reqBuf:%@", reqBuf);
    return reqBuf;
}
@end
```

Then I use the data in Swift, Swift auto convert `Objective-C NSData` to `Swift Data`,  but strange things happen, the value in `Swift Data` is `0x60`, code like belows:

```
public func getOCBuf() -> Data {
    let data = BufUtil.getOCBuf();
    print("getOCBuf: swift data: \(data.hexEncodedString())")
    return data
}
```

the log is like:

```
getOCBuf, oc NSData reqBuf:{length = 1, bytes = 0x10}
getOCBuf: swift data: 60
```

Now I am confused with what happened. Why `0x10` turn into `0x60`, the two number not Binary complement.

Can anybody help me, thanks.

the code:
https://github.com/oncealong/SwiftOcDataConvert

Comment: std::vector seems more c++ than Objective-C. That may be the problem. You may find useful information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713514/stdvector-in-objective-c-method)

Answer (score 0):

It's my falut.

I copy code "how to convert from std::vector to NSData" from stackoverflow, but the code use `[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy`, which lead to all this.

the momory associate with the std::vector has freed after the getOCBuf func return. but the oc NSData and swift Data don't know. it use the origin address and found different value.

To be honest, the app should be crashed, and give a reason.